# Confusión con asignación de una propiedad a un objeto.(JS)

Tags: javascript, poo

Comunidad que tal espero se encuentren bien, vengo con una duda que ojala me ayuden a disiparla:

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj);
obj.accion = "comer";
console.log(obj);
```

Teniendo eso como base porque en los dos `console.log` aparece la propiedad declarada, si una se ejecuta antes que otra. Lo que he llegado a concluir es que *JS* antes de mostrarnos el resultado le da una barrida a todo el archivo y ya sabe que hacer con ese objeto, (como es inmutable maneja la misma referencia) es por eso que vemos en ambos casos la propiedad declarada incluso antes de existir. Seria genial si me ayudaran a resolver dicha duda, (ACLARACIÓN: ESTO NO PASA EN NODE).

Comment: {accion: "comer"}
{accion: "comer"}
en ambos

Comment: Estoy ejecutándolo en chrome y la salida es: `{}
{
  "accion": "comer"
}`. Creo que vendría bien que digas en dónde produce el resultado que obtienes. ¿navegador, cuál? ¿otro entorno?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que describes es un comportamiento normal de la consola de Chrome (efectivamente en Firefox ocurre de manera semejante). Lo que ocurre es una ***evaluacion tardia***, es decir, el objeto mostrado en la consola no se evalua completamente hasta que lo abres. En el ejemplo siguiente se ilustra paso a paso:

[image: Evaluacion por consola en el momento]

El objeto mostrado en el primer console.log() es efectivamente uno vacio (`{}`) pero al hacer clic en el, este se evalua *tardiamente* como una manera de ahorrar recursos. Nótese que aun en el encabezado se muestra como `{}` y abajo se muestra evaluado como { accion: "comer" }, ademas de un pequeño icono azul que dice *"el valor a continuacion fue evaluado justo ahora"*

Una vez abierto en la consola ya se mantiene evaluado con su valor original. Pero como las llamadas a console.log() ocurren en secuencia, nunca veras el estado del objeto original. Si deseas ver el estado del objeto, puedes obligar a hacer una evaluacion directa cambiando a algo como:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Puedes detectar este comportamiento de evaluacion tardia de manera mas notoria al evaluar objetos grandes, por ejemplo intenta:

```
console.log(window)
```

y luego ve a la consola e intenta abrir el detalle del objeto, tardara bastante en responder (hasta se congelará por un tiempo) y saldra un mensaje semejante con el icono `i` en azul

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón, ha quedado claro.

Answer (score 0):

Sabes que preste atención a tu código y tanto en Chrome como Firefox cuando la página inicia por primera vez obj tienen la misma asignación en los 2 consoles. Pero cuando actualizas la página se muestra bien. El problema no es la variable sino el console.log y no sabria decirte porque. Incluso hice pruebas usando var en ves de const pensando que era relacionado al tipo de variable constante.

Si intenas el siguiente código vas a ver que cambia:

```js
        const obj = {};
        console.log(obj.accion);
        obj.accion = "comer";
        console.log(obj.accion);
```